# How to see (Command line) when a file has been created/copied

Tags: networking, windows-xp, file-management

I need to find a way to get the date of a file that has been copied from the network on a given workstation. I see some info when I right-click the file but I know that it's not 3 months ago (The file has been created over the network on that time)

I am using Windows XP Pro and that file has been pushed from Zenworks AOT.

Answer (score 1):

I would play around with `dir /t:[C|A|W]` and figure out which one changes when the file is copied over the network.

For example, on my machine the Access time `/t:A` changes to when the file was copied, but the other two stay the same.

Comment: Ahh it's sad, I don't see the info either... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get that data from a normal command prompt. You can try either of the following:

Non-command line since it is easier. Right-click the file, and go to properties>details. If the information you want is not there, unless you have some additional file monitoring system in place.

From a command line, you can use wmic. For more information, see the following document.

http://www.winplat.net/post/How-to-check-file-properties-through-WMI-command-line.aspx

Comment: Looks like a great command I just discovered. Unfortunately, it did not display the requested info.

Comment: @r0ca It almost certainly does not exist. I was just showing you how to get whatever is there. I have never heard of any such metadata.